how to remove or hide specific column in the export csv code ASP
This is the part of my code where I export the data from the database and exported it into excel CSV, but I want to hide a specific column from the dataset how to I do that using ASP?
'Export to Excel1 Server Behavior
If Request.Form("excel1")="y" Then
    Dim line_rsTaxBillDetails, filename_rsTaxBillDetails, hdr_rsTaxBillDetails,  i_rsTaxBillDetails, lang_rsTaxBillDetails,semi_array_rsTaxBillDetails

    line_rsTaxBillDetails=" "
    hdr_rsTaxBillDetails="1"
    If Instr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"),",")=0 Then
        lang_rsTaxBillDetails=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")
    Else
        lang_rsTaxBillDetails=Left(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"),Instr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"),",")-1)
    End if
    semi_array_rsTaxBillDetails="af|zh-hk|zh-mo|zh-cn|zh-sg|zh-tw|fr-ch|de-li|de-ch|it-ch|ja|ko|es-do|es-sv|es-gt|es-hn|es-mx|es-ni|es-pa|es-pe|es-pr|sw|"
    delim_rsTaxBillDetails=";"
    If inStr(semi_array_rsTaxBillDetails,lang_rsTaxBillDetails & "|")>0 OR inStr(lang_rsTaxBillDetails,"en")>0 Then 
        delim_rsTaxBillDetails=","
    End If
    If hdr_rsTaxBillDetails="1" Then
        For i_rsTaxBillDetails=0 to rsTaxBillDetails.Fields.count-1
            If i_rsTaxBillDetails = rsTaxBillDetails.Fields.count-1 Then
                addComa=""
            Else
                addComa="[_comma_]"
            End If
            line_rsTaxBillDetails=line_rsTaxBillDetails&Replace(rsTaxBillDetails.Fields(i_rsTaxBillDetails).Name,"_"," " )&addComa
        Next
        line_rsTaxBillDetails=line_rsTaxBillDetails&"[_linebreak_]"
    End If

    line_rsTaxBillDetails=line_rsTaxBillDetails&rsTaxBillDetails.GetString(,,"[_comma_]","[_linebreak_]","")
    
    line_rsTaxBillDetails=Replace(line_rsTaxBillDetails,delim_rsTaxBillDetails," " )
    line_rsTaxBillDetails=Replace(line_rsTaxBillDetails,vbCrlf," ")
    line_rsTaxBillDetails=Replace(line_rsTaxBillDetails,"[_linebreak_]",vbCr)
    line_rsTaxBillDetails=Replace(line_rsTaxBillDetails,"[_comma_]",delim_rsTaxBillDetails)
    line_rsTaxBillDetails=Replace(line_rsTaxBillDetails,"DueDate","EarliestDue",1,1,1)
    line_rsTaxBillDetails=Replace(line_rsTaxBillDetails,"Due","DueDate",1,1,1)
    
    
    
    filename_rsTaxBillDetails="PVS_TaxBill_Export_All.csv"
    Response.ContentType="application/xls"
    Response.AddHeader  "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & filename_rsTaxBillDetails
    Response.Write(line_rsTaxBillDetails)
    Response.End()
End if `enter code here`

